# openCV add 2 images in android

Tags: android, opencv

I'm currently doing my final year project which is an android camera apps.

I'm using openCV for my project. I want to add 2 images overlay each other. I realize in C++ has addWeighted function which can add 2 images. However this function can only be used in C++. openCV in JAVA don't have such function.

I found out in JAVA have this function Imgproc.accumulate(src,dst)
Does this function produce the same result as addWeighted in C++?

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html#addWeighted(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20double,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20double,%20double,%20org.opencv.core.Mat)

Comment: possible duplicate of [add watermark small image to large image opencv4android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721774/add-watermark-small-image-to-large-image-opencv4android)

Answer (score 0):

As @berak pointed out in his comment, there is a method '[addWeighted](https://docs.opencv.org/java/3.1.0/org/opencv/core/Core.html)' in the java docs for OpenCV.
I believe this is what you are looking for.